# Why does asyncio subprocess behave differently with created event loop unless you set_event_loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I have this simple async code that spawns `sleep 3` and then waits for it to complete:

```
from asyncio import SelectorEventLoop, create_subprocess_exec, \
    wait_for, get_event_loop, set_event_loop


def run_timeout(loop, awaitable, timeout):
    timed_awaitable = wait_for(awaitable, timeout=timeout, loop=loop)
    return loop.run_until_complete(timed_awaitable)

async def foo(loop):
    process = await create_subprocess_exec('sleep', '3', loop=loop)
    await process.wait()
    print(process.returncode)
```

Notice how it takes a custom `loop`. If I run it with the following:

```
loop = get_event_loop()
run_timeout(loop, foo(loop), 5)
loop.close()
```

It works as expected (after 3 seconds `sleep 3` completes successfully and `0` is printed). However, if I run it with my own event loop:

```
loop = SelectorEventLoop()
run_timeout(loop, foo(loop), 5)
loop.close()
```

I get a `TimeoutError` (from the `wait_for` in `run_timeout`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    _run_async(loop, foo(loop), 5)
  File "test.py", line 7, in _run_async
    return loop.run_until_complete(timed_coroutine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 396, in wait_for
    raise futures.TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
```

The only way I can get my custom event loop to work is if I `set_event_loop()` after creating my own `SelectorEventLoop`:

```
loop = SelectorEventLoop()
set_event_loop(loop)
run_timeout(loop, foo(loop), 3)
loop.close()
```

What gives here? Am I misunderstanding the docs? Must all event loops (that you use) be made the default one? If so, it seems useless to allow custom `loop`s to be passed into many of the async methods (eg. `create_subprocess_exec` and `wait_for`), because the only value you could pass in is `get_event_loop()`, which is the default.

Comment: This looks like a bug in `asyncio.subprocess`. Running the code under Python 3.6 reports [a different exception](https://pastebin.com/77jXwm5m).

Comment: Interesting! Does that exception make sense? Or is the fact that 3.6 raises also a bug? Does doing `set_event_loop()` before `run_timeout()` suppress the error for 3.6?

Comment: I suspect both exceptions are different manifestations of the same bug. (The code in 3.6 is a bit more careful, so it immediately notices that something is not right.)

Comment: But something else is not right: why is your custom-loop code specifying **3** for the timeout? Isn't it expected that you get a timeout waiting for 3 seconds for `sleep 3` to finish (since the subprocess takes some time to set up)?

Comment: That makes sense. I'll file a bug then :) Thanks for the insight. I haven't played around with asyncio too much. Also, no that's just a typo. For the custom-loop code the timeout was also 5.

Comment: With the timeout of 5, my 3.6 exhibits the same behavior as yours.

Comment: I should add, what you're trying to do is definitely supported (except for the bug, of course). It's even easier as of 3.6 and 3.5.3 because there `get_event_loop()` when called from a coroutine (or from an ordinary function invoked from within a coroutine, etc.) returns the *currently running* event loop, not the event loop that is set as the default for the thread. That improves the ergonomy tremendously because it means you don't have to pass `loop` everywhere, and specify it to `wait_for` and elsewhere - once you are inside `loop.run_until_complete (...)`, that will be the asyncio loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's really strange. I debugged the program and found that is hard to say if it is a bug.

Let's make a long story short, when executing `create_subprocess_exec`, you need not only an event loop but also a child watcher(which is used to monitor child processes). But `create_subprocess_exec` doesn't provide a way to let you set custom child watcher, it just use the default watcher which attaches to the default event loop but not current running event loop.

If you use the following code, it will work:

```
from asyncio import SelectorEventLoop, create_subprocess_exec, \
    wait_for, get_event_loop, set_event_loop, get_child_watcher


def run_timeout(loop, awaitable, timeout):
    timed_awaitable = wait_for(awaitable, timeout=timeout)
    return loop.run_until_complete(timed_awaitable)

async def foo():
    process = await create_subprocess_exec('sleep', '3')
    await process.wait()
    print(process.returncode)

loop = SelectorEventLoop()
# core line, get default child watcher and attach it to your custom loop.
get_child_watcher().attach_loop(loop)
run_timeout(loop, foo(), 5)
loop.close()
```

And if you use `set_event_loop` to set default loop, it will also reattach the default child watcher to new default loop. That's why it works.

---

It's really hard to say if it is a bug or a problem about API design. Should `create_subprocess_exec` let you pass a custom watcher? If it should, it will make confusion as you will only touch child watcher when you are working with child processes.

Comment: *It's really hard to say if it is a bug or a problem about API design* Since `create_subprocess_exec` *does* allow passing an explicit `loop`, its unconditional use of the default watcher in the default loop definitely sounds like a bug.

Comment: I don't totally think so as `watcher` to `loop` is something like `flask-extension` to `flask`. Actually, to `loop` itself, it works really well. The OP can even just use `loop.run_until_complete(timed_awaitable)` without passing any redundant `loop` such as `wait_for(awaitable, timeout=timeout, loop=loop)` or `create_subprocess_exec('sleep', '3', loop=loop)`. But I agree if the API design principle is hiding rarely used `watcher`, `create_subprocess_exec` should automatically detect if watcher attaches to running loop or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the flask analogy as I haven't used flask, but the [exception](https://pastebin.com/77jXwm5m) raised by 3.6 shows for code that doesn't explicitly mention the child watcher. Isn't that a bug? I understand that everything would work with the default loop, but it is my understanding that using a non-default loop is supported by asyncio and should work without being aware of the more advanced concepts such as the child watcher.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, I think I agree with @user4815162342 here. I'm working on 3.5.2 so this doesn't apply, but their comment on the question states that `get_event_loop()` inside an async context will return the loop that async is being run under. And thus, that loop should have this child watcher setup. Since `create_subprocess_exec` is run in this context, shouldn't the watcher be available to it?

Comment: Also, I haven't tested, but I believe your snippet will fail because `wait_for` isn't created with `loop=loop`? (At least it does for me on 3.5.2: `got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop`)

Comment: @BaileyParker I have tested the snippet on 3.6.4, and it worked. Maybe that's a bug on 3.5.2? `wait_for` just create a awaitable instance, and `loop.run_until_complete` run this instance so it will be attached to this `loop`.

Comment: @BaileyParker Surely `asyncio.get_event_loop` inside an async context will return the current running loop. But in `create_subprocess_exec` it needs to get child watcher but not event loop. Further, I agree with @user4815162342  that the child watcher shouldn't be a more advanced concept which need to be aware of.